# WCF REST getting response 504 json data too large

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I've been building out my REST services based on the WCF REST templates you can download as a template with Visual Studio 2010. (REST starter kit with key authorization) My web.config looks like this.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="APIKeyAuthorization, SSD.Harrier.Services.REST" />
    </behavior>


  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

When I try to bring back records exceeding 3000 records I get a 504 error in fiddler that it can't process the response. I even tried doing a POST against the same service. Is there a way I can configure this endpoint in my web.config to allow for a larger response? What I'm doing now isn't working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
<configuration> 
<system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```